# Unable to select <li> element from a <ul> list

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#, selenium-webdriver-c#

How do I select a "li" element from a "ul" tag list?

This is my current code

```
vtenants.VT_USDelselectfld.Click(); //Clicks field to display the dropdown 
Thread.Sleep(500);
IList<IWebElement> dropDownMenu = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#typeahead-1358-1464")); //Populates all drop down menues
IList<IWebElement> selectdelegation = dropDownMenu[1].FindElements(By.TagName("li")); //Here is where i receive the error
selectdelegation[1].Click(); //Here i "should" select the dropdown Item
```

I receive the error " Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection."

HTML Example

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu ng-isolate-scope" ng-show="isOpen() 
    <li class="uib-typeahead-match ng-scope" ng-repeat="match in matches 
    track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" etc…
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What if you move the selection to *after* opening the drop-down?

Comment: still receiving the error, i do not get past the IList<IWebElement> selectdelegation step

Comment: `[1]` looks suspicious for a selector based on an ID, because there should only ever be one element with a given ID.

Comment: honestly i don't know what to put there, [1] there it should go a integer value, not a id

Comment: Right, but what's the index of the first thing in a list?

Answer (score 1):

Your locator for the list is wrong, there is not `typeahead-1358-1464` on the HTML.

You can proceed as follows:

```
// You may need to update the locator for uniqueness
listLocator = By.CssSelector("ul.dropdown-menu.ng-isolate-scope");
itemLocator = By.TagName("li");

items = driver.FindElement(listLocator )).FindElements(itemLocator );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:
`IList<IWebElement> selectdelegation = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#typeahead-1358-1464 li"));` //maybe not the best selector - can be improved.

The main idea is to use only one list. Also you can stream and filter the "selectdelegation" and return only a part of the elements as a IList of strings for assertions.